# Spring running external JUnit Jar causes java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

Tags: java, spring, junit, jar

I have project where a user creates and uploads a `jar` filled with `JUnit` tests.  My project is running in `Spring` and for some reason it will not run.  I can hard code some `JUnit` tests and they work fine but once I put the exact code in a .jar file the file won't run.  This is my first question on Stack Overflow and I would appreciate any help.

**Here is my code**

simpletest.jar

```
import org.junit.Test;
public class simpletest {
@Test
public void sayHello() {
    System.out.println("Simple test ran");
}}
```

runjar.java

```
URL[] classLoaderUrls = new URL[]{new URL("file:///c:/Work/simpletest.jar")};
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(classLoaderUrls);
Class<?> appiumClass = null;
try {
    appiumClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("simpletest.simpletest");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// Run the class using JUnitCore
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
Result result = junit.run(appiumClass);
//Display if test was successful
System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
```

Comment: What do you mean by uploading a jar file? To a maven repository ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are loading the `URLClassLoader` you need to supply the current `ClassLoader` for it to load the required JUnit libraries.

```
        //Code to run junit test
        URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(classLoaderUrls, getClass().getClassLoader());
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I spent so much time trying to fix this.  I should also note that the issue was Spring related.  I will update the question to reflect this.